# Ruby - For loop with index and element

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and am trying to figure out the looping syntax.

I have this pseudocode but need to convert it to Ruby

```
# array
search = ["fallacy", "epitome"]

for (i = 0, i > search.length, i++) {

  # Get back the result for each search element 
  response[i] = Word.get_definition(search[i])

}
```

I currently have the following Ruby

```
# create empty response array
response = []

search.each do |element, index|
    # Get back the result for each search element 
    response(index) = Word.get_definition(element(index))
end
```

Comment: if you truely need the index you can use `search.index(element)` but @limelights solution seems to fit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip indices leading to the most straight forward way below

```
search = ["fallacy", "epitome"]
search.each do |element|
    response << Word.get_definition(element)
end
```

[<<](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) is syntactic sugar for [push()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-push).

Have you read the documentation for [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) or done any tutorials?
I could suggest [RubyMonk](https://rubymonk.com/) for you.

Answer (score 3):

A more rubyish approach:

```
response = search.map { |word| Word.get_definition word }
```